# Can I remove email permission for an app in the Facebook developers site?

Tags: facebook, email, permissions

I have created a facebook app and I want remove the default "email" permission. After looking for a solution I have only  found how add others permissions like "user_birthday", "user_website", ... but nothing about remove this "email" permission.

Is possible remove from my application the "email" permission in my apps panel in the facebook developers site?

Comment: If you use API v2.0 or later you have to specify all permissions you need. In API v1.0 there are some default permissions that you can't remove and email is one of them

Comment: When I create an app in the facebook developer panel there are three permission enabled by default: email, public_profile and user_friends. This is independent of the API version. Is in "status and review" page of the facebook app where I want to remove the email permission.

Comment: They are always approved so you can use them. That doesn't mean that the login dialog will ask for them. In API v1.0 the login dialog will always ask for them but in API v2.0 and later you have to specify the permissions you want to ask for

Comment: Exactly, they are always approved by default but I want remove the email permission from facebook developer panel. No ask for this permission is not valid for me by a legal issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked in facebook developers group and the response is that is not possible to disapprove an approved permission.

Answer (score -2):

Need to login before actions below:

1. Click **triangle button** in the top right of Facebook.
2. Select **Settings & Privacy**, then click **Settings**.
3. Click **Apps and Websites** in the *left* menu.
4. Go to the app that you want to adjust who can see your activity, then click View and Edit or **Remove** permissions.

Answer (score -4):

Yes.  You may revoke permissions as follows according to the Facebook documentation.

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked: how does a developer remove a permission at an app level, not for an individual user.

Comment: Totally agree, to use this need to be Facebook guru